# PHP: Find dynamic element from nested associated array

Tags: php, associative-array

I'm working on a function that looks like this:

```
public function myfunction($mainArr, $keys) {
    // $mainArr: a nested associative array
    // $keys: a simple array of strings, example: array('string_1', 'string_2', 'string_3')
    $totalKeys = count(keys);
    if(totalKeys == 1) {
        return mainArr[keys[0]];
    } else if(totalKeys == 2) {
        return mainArr[keys[0]][keys[1]];
    } else if(totalKeys == 3) {
        return mainArr[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]];
    } else if(totalKeys == 4) {
        return mainArr[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]][keys[3]];
    } else if(totalKeys == 5) {
        return mainArr[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]][keys[3]][keys[4]];
    }
    // the same pattern continues..
}
```

I want to change this function into something more dynamic rather than a big list of "if" conditions, is it possible somehow?

Comment: you're missing the `function` keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it for example this way:

```
function get_value(array $source, array $keys) {
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (isset($source[$key])) {
            $source = $source[$key];
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return $source;
}
```

If `$keys` describes an invalid path inside `$source` then `null` will be returned.

Comment: Works perfectly! I spent an hour just thinking of a solution, and you solved it in few seconds! You're a genius!

Comment: @evilReiko: I 'm no genius, just spent lots of time programming. As you learn you always find that yesterday's difficult task is today's easy thingy. This is true for everyone.